# Using the Cocoa framework, when setting a label, an explicit cast to NSString works but stringValue raises an exception. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm setting a UILabel to a value stored in as a NSNumber.
If I do this

```
foo.label.text = [bar stringValue];
```

then I get a NSInvalidArgumentException

However if I cast by doing:

```
foo.label.text = (NSString *)bar;
```

then things work ok.

Can anyone explain why this could be the case?

Comment: What is foo? And make sure you don't have a : in your actual code. `stringValue:` is not the same as `stringValue`. Also, the `NSInvalidArgument` usually includes more info. It would probably be helpful to post that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.

foo is a UILabel.
bar is a NSNumber.

Answer (score 3):

If `bar` is an [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) instance, it is normal that you get a NSInvalidArgumentException, because NSString does not respond to `stringValue` selector; thus the result of the `stringValue` is an invalid value for the text property.

Comment: Wouldn't that throw an "unknown selector sent to object" error?

Comment: You got two errors: "-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector" and a "NSInvalidArgumentException".

Comment: foo is a UILabel and bar is an NSNumber.

Comment: Can you print [bar class] to check that bar is a NSNumber ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, if I do the following:

```
NSNumber *theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[[self theLabel] setText:(NSString *)theNumber];
```

I get the NSInvalidArguementException. But if I do:

```
NSNumber *theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];   
[[self theLabel] setText:[theNumber stringValue]];
```

My label gets set with the number 1.

Are you sure bar is NSNumber? Is foo a view with a label subview defined?

For my example, I have an IBOutlet property on an UIViewController to a UILabel. I put that label in the view using InterfaceBuilder and connected the IBOutlet.